# 2D ARRAY INITIALIZATION?

Tags: c++, arrays

How to initialize a 2d Array by taking elements of Array from user?

```
#include <iostream>
using namepace std;
int main()
{
    int row, col;
    int arr[][];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            cout << "Elements of Array :" << ' ';
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and why have you failed?

Comment: Have you considered searching amongst the hundreds of previous answers?

Comment: Need more details for what are you doing

Answer (score 0):

The bounds for the 2D array must be specified when initializing in this way.

Replacing `int arr[][]` with `int arr[row][col]` can solve your problem, assuming that the number of rows and columns are available.

The following code may be helpful:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int row, col;
        cout << "Number of rows : ";
        cin >> row;
        cout << "Number of columns : ";
        cin >> col;
        int arr[row][col];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                cout << "Enter value for row " << i << " column " << j << " : ";
                cin >> arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << "Elements of Array :" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: ***int arr[row][col];*** is not valid c++. c++ does not allow VLAs. Although some compilers support this as an extension.